# Conectar Mysql con vb6

Tags: mysql, vb6

Estoy intentando conectar vb6 con MySql pero me da error
[image: error de conexión]

Muestro código de conexión

```
Option Explicit

Public cn As ADODB.Connection
Public rs As ADODB.Recordset

Public Sub Conectar()
  Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
  cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=gestvehicular; User=root;Password=123456;Option=3;"
End Sub
```

Tratando de dar de alta un registro y conectarme

```
Private Sub btnGuardar_Click()


If txtNombre.Text <> "" Then
    Dim strSql As String
    strSql = "INSERT INTO gvehi_colores(descripcion) VALUES('" + txtNombre.Text + "')"
    On Error GoTo tratarError
    Dim cmd As New Command
    Conectar
    With cmd
      .ActiveConnection = cn
      .CommandText = strSql
      .CommandType = adCmdText
      .Execute
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Desconectar
    Exit Sub
tratarError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
  End If
End Sub
```

he descargado el conector de mysql [Download Connector/ODBC](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/3.51.html)

He creado el ODBC pero igual me sigue saliendo el error que muestro en la imagen, estoy trabajando sobre SO Windows 7 32 bites sp1 he tratado de actualizar a sp2 pero ya descargue todas las actualizaciones habidas y por haber pero no he logrado conseguir el sp2.

Me servio de fuente para esta implementación este link [MySQL Sample for Visual Basic 6.0 - read/write

][3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024474/mysql-sample-for-visual-basic-6-0-read-write)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pude solucionarlo, gracias a [Conector ODBC 3.51](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-3-51/)

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=myDataBase;
User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Option=3;
```

Link de descarga del conector [Download Connector/ODBC](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/3.51.html)